# regex to ignore html tags but start at a word boundry with varied end anchors

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

**Let me start off by saying I need a regex only solution.**

I'm trying to pull a description from html files with a 3rd program program. **This program is java based, but I cannot manipulate the source code in any way!**. The program I submit the regex into already has another regex script designating where to grab the description from on every page. It has this handy feature to further break down that info into an array if you define the matches within.

**I want to match every sentence in the description regardless of if it is a list item or not. Getting rid of the tags would be ideal since they are causing problems using `\b` to designate where to start the match.**

At first I thought I could just write a regex solution that captures everything between a word boundary and a sentence ending character. Something like this `\b([^.!]+)[.!]` Then I noticed a problem where the description will sometimes have an additional part with list items. What complicates it even more is that sometimes the first part of the list item will be bolded or italicized. Even more rarely there might be a random `<br>` and `</br>` tag in there for reasons I don't understand...

Here is an example description of the common layout from a hilarious article:

```
Children around the world are constantly exposed to the evil “Dolan”, an evil 
duckwho encourages rape, murder, pedophilia, stealing, homosexuality and a range
of other sins.  ”Dolan” is considered a “meme”: an image that makes its way
around the internet via social networks such as Myspace, Friendster, or
Wikipedia.

<li>The duck is based on the character “Donald” created by the company Disney. 
</li><li><b>Dolan, however</b>, is more overtly satanic and enjoys commit crimes
and offending Christianity. </li><li>He is best known for a series of internet 
comics created in the socialist nation of Finland. </li><li><i>Being part of
Scandinavia</i>, the Finnish are clearly followers of Satan and Skrillex. </li>
<li>The comics are written in poor English to distract the viewer from how evil
and offensive they truly are.</li>
```

I tried a couple different things, but am still quite a regex noob and got a variety of different returns that didn't work correctly. This one broke everything up starting with whatever letter was in a tag:

```
(?:<li>|<b>|<i>)?\b([^.!<]+)[.!< ][<lbi/ ]
```

Above code gives an array like this (order gets randomized or at least organized in a way I don't understand)

```
i>
Being Part of Scandinavia
i>
b>
Dolan, however
b>
```

The same one with nearly identical could would leave in some of the html tags which I assume is because `li>` fills the the word boundary requirement. **Note: there is a space on the end of the code below**

```
\b([^.!<]+)[.!]
```

This gives an array like this

```
li>The duck is based on the character “Donald”...
li>li>b>Dolan, however/b>, is more overtly satanic...
```

Like I said earlier I'm a noob to regex and am more than certain I'm using the lookahead wrong.

**Please help me with a solution! I don't know what to try next.**

*PS, I didn't write the article, I copied it from another website. Not trying to be offensive*

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly do you want to match in the description? Delimiters of different parts? Or the different parts themselves? Could please give us an example array, you want to create from the given description?

Comment: sorry, edited to explain

Comment: So do you want to get rid of all the tags between sentences? Or should enclosing tags still be included? Really, an example array would help - even if it costs you 4 minutes of reformatting ;)

Comment: Here's the obligatory link to the ultimate response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I generally agree, but this problem seems specific enough to be attempted with a regex. Especially considering that the OP seems to be obliged to use this regex framework.

Comment: @TravisDtfsuCrum can you run multiple passes on the string? So could you start your regex script once to remove all HTML tags and once again to split the sentences?

Comment: @JimGarrison I've read that a few times for the lulz and I understand the problems with parsing html with regex, but these searches are generally quite specific and are done in a 3rd party java app built specifically for these searches, so its not the same thing. @m.buettner, do you want me to show the items matched in array form? I edited it to say its ideal to not capture the closing tags since they fudging up the `\b` starting anchor.

Comment: @m.buettner unfortunately I am unable to do that. It only scans through the code and cannot manipulate it :(

Comment: The array form would have been ideal, but I think I understand the goal now. The fact that you have to do it all in one pass makes it a bit of a toughie. I'll have a think about it, but there might be some folks around with more hardcore regex skills anyway ;)

Comment: awesome, if you think of anything let me know! I've checked about 50 different pages the app searches to make sure they are all in this format and it appears to be so. Second code works fine for the ones without the additional list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with `\b`, it's just getting in your way.  You don't really need lookarounds, either.  The following regex correctly matches all the sentences in your sample text.  As with @icrf's regex, any tag that's inside a sentence will remain there.  Getting rid of those will require a second step, I don't see any way around that.

```
[^\s<>.!?][^<>.!?]*(?:<[^<>]+>[^<>.!?]*)*[.!?]
```

To break it down:

1. `[^\s<>.!?]` starts matching at the next character that isn't whitespace, an angle bracket, or sentence punctuation.
2. `[^<>.!?]*` continues matching desirable characters, which now includes whitespace.
3. `<[^<>]+>` : If it finds a left angle bracket, this part attempts to match an HTML tag.  Then it goes back to matching non-special characters with `[^<>.!?]*`.  It continues trading off like that until there are no more tags or non-special characters to consume.
4. And finally, `[.!?]` matches the sentence-ending punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
(?:^|(?<=[.!]))(?:</?[a-zA-Z][^>]*>)*([^<][^.!]+)(?:[.!]|$)
```

The idea is to try and match everything **from** a sentence separator character **to** another sentence separator. I'm using [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (the `(?<=[.!])` part) to match the first separator, so the regex doesn't actually consume that character, just checks that it's present in the right position.

Running this regex on your sample article, I get these matches:

```
Children around the world are constantly exposed to the evil...
  ”Dolan” is considered a “meme”: an image that makes its way...
<li>The duck is based on the character “Donald” created by...
</li><li><b>Dolan, however</b>, is more overtly satanic and...
 </li><li>He is best known for a series of internet comics created...
 </li><li><i>Being part of Scandinavia</i>, the Finnish are clearly...
 </li><li>The comics are written in poor English to distract...
```

The resulting matches will still require some processing (i.e. trimming spaces and stripping tags), but at least the regex seems to match sentences correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(?<![</])(?!>)[^.?!]+[.!?]
```

This keeps the HTML tags outside the sentence out of the match, but ones inside the sentence remain and would have to be removed. There isn't any way to get a sentence without them, as it wouldn't be a contiguous match, which is the limit of using just regular expressions to solve this.

The negative look-behind `(?<![</])` and the negative look-ahead `(?!>)` at the beginning are there to keep from matching inside tags as starting points.

```
The duck is based on the character "Donald" created by the company Disney.
Dolan, however</b>, is more overtly satanic and enjoys commit crimes and offending Christianity.
He is best known for a series of internet comics created in the socialist nation of Finland.
Being part of Scandinavia</i>, the Finnish are clearly followers of Satan and Skrillex.
The comics are written in poor English to distract the viewer from how evil and offensive they truly are.
```

The HTML that remains inside won't be valid HTML, as a starting or ending tag might be outside the sentence itself (witness the closing bold without an opening in sentence two).

Comment: alright. This is probably as close as I will get to what I'm looking for. I think there may be an option to ignore all tags in matches, but the problem with that was it was start the match in the middle of a tag. Will try this out right now

Comment: Being HTML, you may also have HTML entities that need to be decoded in the output, too. With one pass of only regular expressions, it sounds like you may not have the tools available to do the job desired properly.

Comment: ah okay thanks for the input. Wasn't sure if it was possible in regex only. I wish I could just use java to aid with this.